# Subsetting array with NULL does not drop dimensions?

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I wonder if there could be any reason behind such default behavior? If there are some consistency quirks about that I would be glad to know.

Below two different queries (resulting into 20 and 0 lengths), but I would expect them to have same behavior about dropping redundant dimensions. Subset by `NULL` seems to keep empty dimension for some reason. `?drop` states:

> Delete the dimensions of an array which have only one level.

What's the point of keeping 0 level dimensions with `drop=TRUE`?

I'm developing array-like class and I've hit inconsistency to `base::array` because of that. Should I report such issue to R dev platform?

```
set.seed(1L)
ar.dimnames = list(color = sort(c("green","yellow","red")), 
                   year = as.character(2011:2015), 
                   status = sort(c("active","inactive","archived","removed")))
ar.dim = sapply(ar.dimnames, length)
ar = array(sample(c(rep(NA, 4), 4:7/2), prod(ar.dim), TRUE), 
           unname(ar.dim),
           ar.dimnames)
r1 = ar["green",,,drop=TRUE]
dimnames(r1)
#$year
#[1] "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014" "2015"
#
#$status
#[1] "active"   "archived" "inactive" "removed" 
#
length(r1)
#[1] 20
r2 = ar[NULL,,,drop=TRUE]
dimnames(r2)
#$color
#NULL
#
#$year
#[1] "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014" "2015"
#
#$status
#[1] "active"   "archived" "inactive" "removed" 
#
length(r2)
#[1] 0
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want the output to look like. Should it have dim of 0 5 4 or just 5 4? In the former case, it's natural that the dimnames should stick around. I would probably go with `ar[NA_integer_,,]` rather than `NULL` or `0L`.

Comment: Relevant c code: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/de36cb25a08cd14db5569b85cc6335d39caa0cf6/src/main/array.c#L306

Comment: Yeah, but the fact is that 0L level dimension basic info is even less useful than 1L level dimension info. `drop=T` should handle that if it is already dropping dimension which ships some info

Comment: Handle it how? Would you have dim be c(5,4)? If so, what content would/should it have?

Comment: yes, 0 length dimension could also be dropped resulting `c(5,4)`, current of `dimnames` would be as is now without the first element

Comment: This behavior is not documented (to my best knowledge). Thus, you shouldn't expect consistency. It might be worth mentioning it on the r-devel mailing list, but you shouldn't have high expectations. Possible outcomes are (i) nothing, (ii) documentation of this behavior, (iii) a change of behavior (more likely if you provide a patch), (iv) a very terse message explaining the errors of your reasoning.

Comment: @Roland I guess it is documented: `?drop` says "Delete the dimensions of an array which have only one level." There's no mention of handling zero levels.

Comment: I'm still not clear about the output you expect. Okay, so it should have dim c(5,4), but what should its content be? Can you write out the object you expect like `structure(...)` or some other way, or is it inconsistent with how R models objects? I think `Reduce(\`*\`, lengths(dimnames(x)))` has to equal `length(x)` and `Reduce(\`*\`,dim(x))`, generally.

Comment: @Frank nice catch. I would expect 0 length results, so it basically cannot have `c(5,4)` dim which won't evaluate to 0 when `prod(c(5,4))`. 0 dimension is then correct as `prod(c(0,5,4))` will evaluate to 0 length. The answer from @user7669 is quite on point here too.

Comment: interesting thing is that `apply` sum over such empty array to collapse NULL dimension will expand the array to non-zero length...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact if you use drop=FALSE in your example you will see that in the first case the first dimension has 1 level, while in the second it has 0 levels. So the behaviour of drop is not totally inconsistent. Sorry, I see that you realized this. But the consequence of this is the fact that r2 is an array with NO entries. As the number of entries must be equal to the product of the of the dimensions, dropping the first dimension as you would like would produce an error. In other terms: you can drop when you have one level because 1*5*4=5*4, while you cannot drop 0 levels because 0*5*4=0, which is different from 5*4.

To specifically answer your questions:

1. Yes, there are reasons behind this default behaviour. You cannot drop a dimension with 0 levels because if the remaining dimensions have more than zero levels, after dropping, the number of entries (0) will no more match the product of dimension.
2. The point of keeping 0 levels dimensions is that the result of subsetting an array with NULL is an array with NO entries. This is different from a slice of an array (1 level) which still has entries, and cannot be viewed as an array with one dimension less. So dropping doesn't make sense in for 0 levels (probably the only other possible behaviour would be drop all the dimensions if one has 0 levels, but you would lose the info e.g. on dimnames).
3. No, you should not report this issue to R dev platform.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some details to the answer. Hope that now it is more similar to a proper answer.

Comment: @Milap Thanks. I have specifically answered to the questions. Hope that now it is more similar to a proper answer.

Comment: Yep - _that's_ an answer! Thanks for taking the constructive advice and acting on it. Good luck!